# Calling a server through your app

Tags: xcode, osx-server

I am trying to make my app call an online live server from my mac with Apple's server program, and take data from it but I do not know how to do this regards the server and the code in Xcode. can you help me please?

thanks a lot

Comment: Start by looking at `AFNetworking`, and more specifically its `AFHTTPClient` class. It has all you need.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to do some research. No one is going to "tell" you how to do this.

If you are interested in AFNeworking, as Cyrille mentioned, you should take a look at the project's samples: https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/tree/master/Example

Also, make sure that your server has proper ports opened. That may include checking your firewall and/or router, etc ...

Good luck.